# Price not updating in cart when the store is switched to another store

Tags: magento

We have magento1.9 installed. In this site we have products with multiple options. We have added custom price for the options and it works fine. The product with the custom options and a total price can be added to the cart. The custom price is set using the code

```
$quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price['price'])
```

My magento is multi language store with different currencies. The base price is in GBP. When we switch it to a different store the cart currency is updated but the price remains the same, it does not decrease or increase respectively with respect to the store currency.

Answer (score 1):

Hi encountered the same issue on Magento ver. 1.9.3.3.
To solve I create an observer on controller_action_predispatch

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <updatecartonstorechange>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>megaobserver/Observer</class>
                    <method>updateCartOnStoreChange</method>
                </updatecartonstorechange>                  
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

inside the method I checked if a store change was called, and forced update the cart:

```
public function updateCartOnStoreChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $store = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('___store', false);
    if(!($store===false)){
        $currentQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $items = $currentQuote->getAllVisibleItems();
        $cartData = Array();
        foreach ($items as $key =>$value) {
            $cartData[$value->getItemId()] = ['qty'=>$value->getQty()];
        }
        if(!empty($cartData)){
            $this->_updateShoppingCart($cartData);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prices in Magento are either per-website or global, not per-store (view). However, I don't think that is your problem, I believe your issue is just bad code used in templates to actually render the prices in front-end.

Could you provide the corresponding code from the templates (.phtml files) of the pages in which you see the wrong prices?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue. Before adding custom price is set based on height and width and in cart it is showing correctly. But while changing the currency, the item price is not changing. I am using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` this event. and my code is like

```php
 public function updateProductCartPrice($observer, $new_price){
     $quote_item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
     $quote_item  = ( $quote_item->getParentItem() ? $quote_item ->getParentItem() : $quote_item  );

    if($new_price):

        $quote_item ->setCustomPrice($new_price);
        $quote_item ->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
        $quote_item ->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

    endif;

  }
```